# Why is Install/Update "hidden" in Help menu in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

This is just theme for discussion, nothing important.

Could someone tell me why is the Install/Update functionality placed in Help menu in Eclipse? I don't find this very user friendly and intuitive and it seems a little ilogical for me.

Is it because it should be there for some reason, or because users are used to it, or because it's just legendary and typical only for eclipse ;-) ?

EDIT: Ok, I can underestand that if you look in Help -> About, you can see application version there, so maybee you would like to get a newer one.. But what about plugins? Other applications usually have some plugin manager in Tools menu or something similar

Answer (score 2):

This is actually very common to put the Update option in Help. Firefox does this and so do many other applications. I don't know why this appears in Help and not a "Tools" sort of menu as it is sometimes. Perhaps the idea is the "Help this doesn't work" and maybe an update will "fix" a problem. I think it's debatable.

Comment: You're right, but in Firefox and others you also have a plugin manager or something similar in Tools. I ment the install plugin functionality. Edited my question acording to it..

Comment: As far as plugins, I agree it is odd. One thing to note that the line is sort of blurry in Eclipse between updating it and its plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Dude,

If you have some serious feedback on Eclipse and you want to make a difference, I suggest you open up a defect in [Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/). The Eclipse team is very attentive and open to suggestions. BTW, you can also open and look up defects from within Eclipse, using the Mylyn plugin. Start with the "planning" perspective.

Comment: hm ... I'm suprised you didn't invite the user to create a new distribution of Eclipse that just puts the option in the desired place. :)

Comment: Opening bugs is a simple way of giving something back to the Eclipse development community. Obviously he cares, otherwise he wouldn't bother posting this question.

Comment: Well, I don't think it is a bug.. I think it's a result of someone's decision and that it is ment to be there.. But I just wonder why :) ?